# How to cancel a SSH connection while a process is running?

Tags: python, ssh, nohup, nice

I am using `ssh` to connect to another (faster) computer in order to run some python code there. As I expect it to run several hours, I would like to disconnect after running it, like this:

```
$ ssh user@my-other-computer
$ python file.py &
$ exit
```

However, if I try this, I get the message:

```
zsh: you have running jobs.
```

I tried using `nohup`:

```
$ nohup nice python file.py &
```

but to no avail.

> How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Is there any (error) output when you use the `nohup` command?

Comment: The out put is `usage: nohup [--] utility [arguments]`

Comment: Seems like a Syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `nohup` does not work (maybe because of the `nice`, it could work without the `nice` command) but there are alternatives:

- `screen` creates a new terminal that is not bound to your session (you can detach a screen session usind `screen -d` or `Contr+A` and then `:detach` and attach to it again using `screen -r`).  You can run the comand using `screen python file.py`
- `tmux` is a terminal multiplexer. It is like screen but has more features and it's faster. You can open a tmux session using `tmux` and run `python file.py` in the newly created session. You can detach using `Contr+B` and `d` or `tmux detach-client`.
- `disown` is a shell command that *disowns* all jobs from the current shell that you can close it and the jobs will stay running.